# slappasswd: symbol lookup error undefined symbol ber_sockbuf_io_udp

Tags: linux, centos, yum, centos-7, openldap

I have CentOS 7 (`3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64`) from Pivotal Greenplum Sandbox VM.

I tried to install OpenLDAP:

```
sudo yum install openldap openldap-servers openldap-clients -y
```

But when I run `slappasswd -s mypassword`, I got a weird error below:

```
slappasswd: symbol lookup error: slappasswd: undefined symbol: ber_sockbuf_io_udp
```

I have not seen this anywhere even if I use a blank Centos 7 from scratch.

So what caused `slappasswd` to break and how to fix it?

**UPDATE 1**

I executed `ldd /usr/sbin/slappasswd` and here is the output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcb7dd3000)
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/local/greenplum-db/./lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f285ed37000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/local/greenplum-db/./lib/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f285eb29000)
libdb-5.3.so => /lib64/libdb-5.3.so (0x00007f285e762000)
libsasl2.so.3 => /lib64/libsasl2.so.3 (0x00007f285e545000)
libnss3.so => /lib64/libnss3.so (0x00007f285e21a000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f285dffe000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f285ddc7000)
libslapi-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/libslapi-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f285dba6000)
libltdl.so.7 => /lib64/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f285d99c000)
libwrap.so.0 => /lib64/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007f285d791000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f285d3cd000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f285d1b3000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/local/greenplum-db/./lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f285cf41000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/local/greenplum-db/./lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f285caba000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f285c8b6000)
libnssutil3.so => /lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x00007f285c689000)
libplc4.so => /lib64/libplc4.so (0x00007f285c483000)
libplds4.so => /lib64/libplds4.so (0x00007f285c27f000)
libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x00007f285c041000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056487cd59000)
libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f285be3d000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f285bc24000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f285ba1b000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your executable probably links to the wrong library.

You can use `ldd /<insert path to slappasswd here>/slappasswd` 
to find out which dynamic libraries are pulled in. Use e.g. `whereis slappasswd` to find its path.

Have a look [here](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/393900-ldap-server-start-error) where such a case is described.

**Update:**

Changing the directory order on the LD path did sort out matters for @HP.:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the result from `ldd`. So I guess you are right. A bunch of them is pointing to `/usr/local/greenplum-db/./lib` instead. How do I fix that?

Comment: You wrote you use a Privotal Greenplum Sandbox VM. So that arrangement might be on purpose. If you rename `/usr/local/greenplum-db/lib` to `/usr/local/greenplum-db/lib.old` it might result in a working `slappasswd` but in a broken Greenplum installation. If you need both working I would try to get support from the Greenplum folks, it might be that installing the extra OpenLDAP package was not the proper step here.

Comment: I found out doing this did the trick `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. If you add into answer, I can accept it. Thanks for the hints.

Comment: Glad to hear you could solve your issues.